# Controlar User Agent para chamar iFrame

Tags: javascript, html5

Bom dia!! Eu estava fazendo algumas coisas aqui e decidi colocar um iFrame na página, mas que fosse carregado com o User Agent de algum outro navegador. Apenas para entender o comportamento do site.

Isso é possível com HTML5 e Javascript?

Senão, dá pra fazer isso com cURL em PHP? E como faço?

---

Eu consegui fazer isso com cURL, mas queria fazer com iFrame. A solução, em PHP, foi:

```
<?php
$url = "http://example.com";
$ch = curl_init();
$curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; de-ch; HTC Sensation Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
curl_exec($ch);
```

Jogando tudo isso numa DIV, consigo alguma coisa, mas quero fazer com iFrame, porque assim eu tenho problema com imagens, o que resolvi com uma base tag, mas prefiro iFrame.

Comment: Estás a referir-te a juntar uma iFrame aqui no [pt.so]? ou numa página tua? O que queres dizer com "mas que fosse carregado com o User Agent de algum outro navegador"?

Comment: Testou [minha sugestão com iframe](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76806/2998) Héliton?

Comment: Testei sim, funcionou conforme esperado. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu havia esquecido de agradecer porque fui testar e esqueci kkkkkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trocar o *user agent* de um `iframe`, ou de uma pagina é possivel com `javascript` da seguinte forma:

Defina a função para setar o *user agent*:

```
function setUserAgent(window, userAgent) {
    if (window.navigator.userAgent != userAgent) {
        var userAgentProp = { get: function () { return userAgent; } };
        try {
            Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent', userAgentProp);
        } catch (e) {
            window.navigator = Object.create(navigator, {
                userAgent: userAgentProp
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Depois selecione o objeto `window` de onde você deseja alterar o *user agent*:

```
var mWindowFrame = document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow;
```

Chame a função passando o objeto `window` e o novo valor do *user agent* a ser setado:

```
setUserAgent(mWindowFrame, 'Meu User Agent falso!');
```

Pronto a partir desse ponto o valor do *user agent* será o que você setou!

**[Exemplo completo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/f2rfz9wt/1/)**